# Parsing html table xcode

Tags: objective-c, html-table, html-parsing

How I can in Objective-C parse the entire table from html, save it, and show in WebView later in offline?

Comment: Why parse? Why not just save the HTML directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NSXMLDocument and analyse the DOM -- it's works using xpath but can be used with KVC
(it abstracts the whole HTML syntax)

Comment: Ok, how i can save it, and to show in WebView later in offline?)

Comment: html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>%@</body></html>", node.XMLString];


(written inline, but something like this :D)